# Count the difference between two nbr i in the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Was wondering if there is a possibilty to write 1 query that ask the difference between two nbr in database or do I have to ask first for the 1 nbr and then store it in one variable and the do the same procedure for the seconde nbr and the   take the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the query you have for fetching one nbr? (Btw, what is an nbr?)

Comment: select max from aggregates where name='tagg' and date between date1 and date2;
select min from aggregates where name='tagg' and date between date1 and date2.
I will get the max integer of max and the the min value of the min. there i would like two have the differance and if it´s possibly to make it in one query.

Comment: The nbr is a double and that is a diffrence in a tank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  max,
  min,
  max - min as difference
from 
  aggregates 
where 
  name='tagg' and date between date1 and date2;
```

Comment: Thnaks!! That was fixing it for me!!